# authorization token sending on get but not on post

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

SO basically i am working on axios and i am sending a token in authorization header in both get and post but i can get the token if i do get request but not if i do it with post i didnt recieve the header on post i am sharing the code here please see the issue

GET request

```
 axios
              .get(
                "https://localhost:8000/user/delete/"+data+"",
                {
                  headers: {Authorization:`Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('token')}`}
                }
              )
              .then((response) => {
                console.log(response)
              if(response.data.status===200){
                window.location.href='/dashboard'
              }
              else if(response.data.status===404){
                console.log('Your token has been expired')
              }
              else if(response.data.status===403){
                console.log('Incorrect Token')
              }
              else if(response.data.status===402){
                console.log('Token does not matched')
              }
          })
        }

    }
```

[image: Here i am geeting the token on get request]

POST

```
      axios
         .post(
                "https://localhost:8000/user/update", 
                {
                   id:document.getElementById("id").value,
name:document.getElementById("name").value,
email:document.getElementById("email").value,
password:document.getElementById("password").value,
retype:document.getElementById("retype").value,
contact:document.getElementById("contact").value
                },
                {
                  headers: {
                    "Content-type": "application/json",
                    "Authorization":`Bearer${localStorage.getItem('token')}`
                  }
              },
              )
              .then((response) => {
                window.location.href='/dashboard'
          })
        }
```

[image: No token on post request]

Comment: You're missing a space between "Bearer" and "the token" on the Auth header in the post. "Bearer" is the schema and has to be separated from the actual token piece by a space. "Authorization":`Bearer${localStorage.getItem('token')}` wrong. "Authorization": `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('token')}` right

Comment: Still there is no token i recieve on pos request

Comment: ANyone up for this need this solved